# Exclude certain files or folders when do gradlew clean task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

Is there a way to exclude a certain folders of files when Gradle clean task running?

I have tried below, but it doesn`t work.

> build.gradle

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
    excludes '**/findbugs/**'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot exclude directories for a Gradle copy task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768723/cannot-exclude-directories-for-a-gradle-copy-task)

Comment: @DCTID thanks DCTID, but i wonder how to exclude folder or file with clean task.